# How can abstract base class daemon call its pure virtual method?

Tags: c++

A class (say class A) derived from a ACE_Task_Base has a pure virtual method:

```
virtual int handler(int) = 0;
```

Class B is derived from class A and has an implementation of the pure virtual method. No problem.

Now, the problem is: The daemon thread of class A calls this pure virtual method:

```
int A::svc(void)
{
    while(true) {
        // some function;
        handler(void);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the method is called from an object of B, there is no question. But, how can this pure virtual method be called from A?

Comment: So, you're looking at a 'How does this happen' right? I'll modify the question accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Calling `handler` from `A` will use the definition provided in `B`.

It's safe to call a pure virtual method anywhere (**except in constructors**) because the compiler will prevent you from directly creating an object that has unimplemented pure virtual methods. Therefore, any object you can deal with should have all of its methods implemented, so you don't have to worry about things like this.

Comment: I'd like to suggest an edit - "any object you can deal with should have all of its methods implemented" - can be expanded to include the very, very dangerous practice of calling functions from constructors. In the case of pure virtuals, this leads to a runtime crash.

Comment: @Sharadh, I added a short (but bold) mention of that problem. Your comment is still there to say the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like it's been pointed out, this will work. How it works, though, requires some diving into how inheritance is implemented in C++. In short, the pure-virtual function tells the compiler "Assume this function exists, and I'll give you the definition later". This 'later' happens when B is defined. This is why you're able to call a function from A that 'doesn't exist' in A.

Inheritance of functions can be broken down to simply a map (also called `vtable`, `virtual table` etc) of [function signatures](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~storm/C++/ProgrammingTerms/FunctionSignatures.html) to memory addresses.

When normal functions are inherited, the derived class *adds to this map*. It doesn't matter if the signature is the same, the class will add a new entry. What's more - it'll add it in such a way that this 'new' signature is what is executed for objects of type `Derived`.

However, when `Base` has `virtual` functions are inherited, the `Dervied` class *replaces the map entry* if it finds an identical signature. What this means is that anybody who tries to call this signature on this object will now call the new address, i.e, the overridden function. This is true of all virtual functions.

Pure virtual functions are a special case, more of an addition for design considerations. They *force* a programmer to implement certain functions, and find use either in the [Interface](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_interfaces.htm) design component or [Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern (among others). Any class inheriting a pure virtual function and not providing an implementation will not be instantiated - this will throw a compile time error.

**Note on contructors**

The 'entries' for functions are done during construction of an object. The `Base` is first constructed with the information available to it, then the `Dervied`, who then overrides the information in the `Base` vtable. *This means that if you call a virtual function from a constructor, the result is not as expected.* The virtual function will resolve to the `Base`'s definition, and in the case of pure-virtual functions, crash trying to dereference a null address.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Now, if there are two classes, B & C, that are derived from A and each has implementation of handler() (differently), then, in the above case, which handler() will be invoked?

Comment: @user3614915 The most specific/recent/derived implementation is used for virtual functions. If it works like a 'rewrite', the last rewrite gets the call, right? In your case, if `A:foo()` is virtual and B, C derive separately from A and implement `foo()`, a *pointer of type A that points to B will call B:foo() and a pointer of type A that points to C will call C:foo()*.